# mysqli_fetch_assoc() return null

Tags: php

this is my codes

```
$connect=dbConfig();
$query="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=$postId";
$res=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$sum=[];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
{
    $sum[]=$row;
}
    return $sum;
```

when I call this function this function return me null

but if I use this code

```
$connect=dbConfig();
$query="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=$postId";
$res=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
return $row;
```

function return me value

and this is a picture of my table in MySQL
[an image of my table in MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrIVc.jpg)

Comment: Try giving `mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) or die(mysqli_error($connect))` and tell us what's happening?

Comment: @parveenKumarPurushothaman thanks for your help  die(mysqli_error($connect)); I use this but nothing was showed

Answer (score 3):

There is a `;` after `while` statement. Remove it and it should be fine. The second code is alright. If you want to use another method, you can use `mysqli_fetch_row()`.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
    $sum[]=$row;
}
```

Comment: It's not `mysql_fetch_assoc()` it's `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: updated. sorry, i miss this.

Comment: Why doesn't `_fetch_assoc` work in a `while`…?!

Comment: thanks, a lot yes I don't saw that semicolon

Comment: i should say that `_fetch_assoc` is unnecessary with `while`

Comment: How's that…? I think you're entirely on the wrong path there.

Comment: `_fetch_assoc` returns an entire row of data. no need to use `while` to get all results

Comment: `_fetch_assoc` gets *one row* as an associative array. `_fetch_row` gets *one row* as a numerically indexed array. You still need a `while` in both cases if you want to fetch more  than one row.

Comment: @deceze is right here.

Comment: my bad. i didn't read carefully at `_fetch_assoc` tutorial.

Comment: There is no problem in using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in a while loop.

Comment: update my answer